# Why Emulator is becoming very slow after changing the configuratio which solved the black flickering issue of the emulator screen

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator, ui-automation

I initially faced the flickering issue when i created the device and i made changes in the configuration file like (hw.gpu.mode = auto)  to (hw.gpu.mode = guest) which solved the flickering issue but the emulator has become very slow.

tried to solve the flickering issue but that has been solved by making the changes in the config file but the emulator has become very slow.

Comment: You may want to try another emulator like Genymotion Free https://www.genymotion.com/download/